# accessing a json dictionary of an object from list of objects

Tags: html, json, django, dictionary, django-views

I am new to django and I am working on project where I am storing a key value pair dictionary as JSON in database.

Now later I want to show it on the html page all the list of packages but not able to access those key value pair as dictionary.

here is my

**models.py**

```
class Packages(models.Model):
    package_ID = models.AutoField("Package ID", primary_key=True)
    package_Name = models.CharField("Package Name", max_length=30, null=False)
    attribute_values = models.CharField("Item Details JSON", max_length=500, null=False)
    package_Price = models.IntegerField("Package Price", null=False, default=0.00)
    quantity = models.IntegerField("Quantity", null=False, default=00)
    prod_ID = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product ID (FK)")
```

**its data entry is something like this**

```
package_ID = 1
package_Name = "basic card"
attribute_values = {"sizes": "8.5 in. x 11 in.", "Colour": "Full-Color Front - Unprinted Back",}
package_Price = 200
quantity = 400
prod_ID = 1

package_ID = 2
package_Name = "best card"
attribute_values = {"sizes": "8.5 in. x 11 in.", "Colour": "Full-Color Front - Unprinted Back",}
package_Price = 200
quantity = 500
prod_ID = 1
```

here the problem is that **attribute_values** fields stores a JSON string so I have to convert it in dictionary first and then have to access its dictionary.

the steps I want to do:

- get all the packages having same product key:
- now get the attribute_values of those packages
- and convert that JSON into dictionary
- then display the attribute_values of each package separately in html in particular block.

I want output something like this:

[image: desired output]

but I am getting this:

[image: output I am getting]

Comment: What version of Django do you use? Try upgrading to 3.1 or greater if lower than that (you can use JSONField in those versions), or if your database is PostgreSQL you can use it's JSONField.

Comment: I am using Django 3.1 but I am a newbie so I don't  have musch idea how to use it can you please give an example of this

Answer (score 0):

With Django version >=3.1 one can simply use [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) for storing JSON in databases.

It is supported for the following databases:

> JSONField is supported on MariaDB 10.2.7+, MySQL 5.7.8+, Oracle,
> PostgreSQL, and SQLite 3.9.0+ (with the [JSON1 extension
> enabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#sqlite-json1)).

Using the `JSONField` should be pretty simple:

```py
class Packages(models.Model):
    # other fields
    attribute_values = models.JSONField()
```

Let's say we have an instance of `Packages` we can simply set a dictionary / variable that can be valid JSON on to `attribute_values`:

```py
package.attribute_values = {"sizes": "8.5 in. x 11 in.", "Colour": "Full-Color Front - Unprinted Back",}
package.save()
```

This will be stored as JSON in the database.

When we want to access this in python it would automatically be deserialized to their python value:

```py
package.attribute_values['new_key'] = 'new value'
package.save()
```

Considering your current problem with the text field you need to simply convert your string to equivalent python objects. This can be done using `json.loads`:

```py
import json

attribute_values_dictionary = json.loads(package.attribute_values)
```

You can also add a method to your model to do this for you:

```py
import json

class Packages(models.Model):
    # Your fields
    
    def attribute_values_to_python(self):
        return json.loads(self.attribute_values)
```

Now in the view you can simply write:

```py
attribute_values_dictionary = package.attribute_values_to_python()
```

In the template you can simply write:

```
{{ package.attribute_values_to_python }}
```